# python, pandas, drop rows by condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

hello I need help to drop some rows by the condition: if the estimated price minus price is more than 1500 (positive) drop the row

```
    price      estimated price 
 0  13295                13795
 1  19990                22275
 2   7295                 6498
```

for example only the index 1 would be drop
thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`pd.drop()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) in which you can drop specific rows by index. :

```
>>> df.drop(df[(df['estimated price']-df['price'] >= 1500)].index)

   price  estimated price
0  13295            13795
2   7295             6498
```

`index` 1 is dropped.

Note that this method assumes that your `index` is unique. If otherwise, `boolean indexing` is the better solution.

Comment: Yes it only works with unique index. I assumed that though, based on the sample data we have above.

Comment: thanks for the tip, please continue pointing these things out. we are all here to learn :)

Comment: ya, only thinking sometimes about another solutions ;)

Answer (score 4):

Change logic for get all rows if less or equal like `1500` after subtracting in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.le`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.le.html):

```
df1 = df[df['estimated price'].sub(df['price']).le(1500)]
```

working like invert mask for greater like `1500`:

```
df1 = df[~df['estimated price'].sub(df['price']).gt(1500)]
```